# nginx user permissions

Tags: nginx

I have switched recently to nginx from Apache2.

I have setup everything and when I `sudo nginx -t` it says everything is fine.

but when I just do `nginx -t` I get the following errors:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2012/10/24 12:22:16 [warn] 23075#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2012/10/24 12:22:16 [emerg] 23075#0: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/ssl/private/myapp.key") failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib error:140B0002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib)
```

Respectively the following seem also to restart without any error:

```
sudo service nginx reload
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Is this expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is expected if you run `nginx -t` as a non-privileged user. When running the commands with `sudo(8)`, you run them as the root-user and you will have access to open the logfiles which you don't seem to have as your personal user.

`nginx -t` should be run as the same user as you start nginx from for correct results.